# Javascript: Change <link rel="stylesheet"> media attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If a user visits my website from a desktop computer, in my HTML I call a CSS style like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css" media="all and (min-device-width:768px)" />
```

Using plain javascript (no framework) how can I change the media attribute from `"all and (min-device-width:768px)"` to `"all and (min-width:768px)"` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it an id and change the attribute value:

```
<link id="foo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css" media="all and (min-device-width:768px)" />
```

And the jQuery part:

```
$("#foo").attr("media", "all and (min-width:768px)");
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/qigicunalo/1/)

---

No jQuery version

```
document.querySelector("#foo").setAttribute("media", "all and (min-width:768px)");
// or
document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("media", "all and (min-width:768px)");
```

Comment: Multumesc / Thank you ! :) Will make this the accepted answer.

Comment: I know this is a nitpick, but why use `document.querySelector` to just grab an element by Id? Use `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Because it is almost the same with the jQuery selectors. Sure, probably `getElementById` would be a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have access to source code and can't set id for `link`, first you have to do is to filter links by media attribute. Then just set new attribute value to filtered:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var link = links[i];
    if(link.getAttribute('media') === 'all and (min-device-width:768px)')
        link.setAttribute('media', 'all and (min-width:768px)');
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exo0ux67/)